# Export full content of shortened column headers with Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

After hours of searching and reading other related questions but that have not helped me at all, I come here for help.

I have a table with columns that have looooong names, to avoid spacing problems I used tooltips and shortened header names, but when exporting to csv, I would like to export the whole name of the header not the shortened version. (Not all the columns have long names)

Here is an example:

[LIVE DATATABLE DEMO](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/78/)

So for instance, for the second column `(U.N)` I would like that when I export the table, the header is displayed as: `Full User Name`.

What I've tried:

```
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'csv',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: [1],
            format: {
                body: function (data, rowIdx, colIndex, cellNode) {
                    if (colIndex == 1) { 
                        data = "Full User Name"
                    };
                    return data;
                }
            }
        },
        charset: 'utf-8',
        bom: true,
    }
]
```

I basically tried to change the value manually for the second column `[1]` without success.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
format: {
    header: function() {}
}
```

instead of:

```
format: {
    body: function() {}
}
```